# Is there a way to not be Thane?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the main quest line you are made the Thane of Whiterun. But I do not want to be Thane. Is there a way to be stripped of the title of Thane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

As you can [read here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thane_(Title)), you can only lose your Thane status if the Jarl position is changed during a Civil War battle. Whiterun, specifically, you have to fight for the Stormcloaks to change your Thane status.

Comment: Be careful: After doing this, you can reacquire the title in a dialog option with the new jarl, and after that you're stuck with it for good.